# Writing 2 names (with spaces) in C++ (cin command)

Tags: c++

I am beginner to the C++ and was trying to build first codes. Right now I'm trying to learn cin command but there is a problem. When I use this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    string name;
    string surname;
    cout<<"Please enter your name: ";
    cin>>name;
    cout<<"Please enter your surname: ";
    cin>>surname;
    cout<<"Your name: "<<name <<endl;
    cout<<"Your surname: "<<surname;
}
```

The output is:

```
Please enter your name: aaa bbb
Please enter your surname: Your name: aaa
Your surname: bbb
```

So when I use 2 names in the 'name' variable, this happens. But when I just write 'aaa' in the name and 'bbb' in the surname, it works perfectly fine:

```
Please enter your name: aaa
Please enter your surname: bbb
Your name: aaa
Your surname: bbb
```

What do I have to do? Thanks.

Comment: The problem is not writing its reading. You may want to use `std::getline()` to read the full line of input. `cin>>name;` reads up till the first whitespace leaving the rest of the input for the next cin >>. I did not answer because I am sure a question like this has hundreds of duplicates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `getline` function:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    string name, surname;

    cout << "Please enter your name: ";
    getline(cin, name);

    cout << "Please enter your surname: ";
    getline(cin, surname);

    cout << "Your name: " << name << endl;
    cout << "Your surname: " << surname;
}
```

`cin` reads just till the first space, but `getline` reads till the first new line. That means that `cin` only takes the first word, and the next word "rests" unpicked on the console. When the next `cin` comes, it takes that "resting" word.

You have to include the `#include<string>` header when using function `getline`. You specify the input type as first argument (that's what you put in the parentheses – in our case `cin`), and as second argument is the string where you want to save that value. For example, `getline(cin, input);`. If you don't use `namespace std;`, you must also specify the namespace, so like this: `std::getline(std::cin, input)`.

If you are still learning C++, you won't understand this, but maybe a little later: [there are actually two forms ("overloads") of `getline` function](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/getline/): one is like I said before (`istream& getline (istream& is, string& str, char delim);`), but another also uses the 3rd parameter (`istream& getline (istream& is, string& str);`), like this: `getline(cin, input, ';');`. With that code, the input stream ends the input at the first semicolon. Note the ' sign, not " sign!

Comment: Yes I'm new at C++, it's been 2-3 days. I really appreciate your detailed explanation.

Comment: Alright, I wish you luck with the programming. C++ is a really nice language.